# Order of fields in a lucene query

Tags: solr, lucene

Does the order of fields matter in a lucene query?

For instance,

q = A && B && C

Lets say A appears in a million documents, B in 10000, C in 1000.

while the results would be identical irrespective of the order in which you AND
A, B and C, will the response times of the following queries differ in any way?

C && B && A

A && B && C

Does Lucene/Solr pick the best query execution plan in terms of both space and time for a given query?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if query is `A AND B AND C` or `C AND B AND A`, the query execution time will be same.
Also if you do an AND , all the query terms need to be be present for the document to be returned, so the Document frequency would be the same.
However, the term frequency would differ and hence the score.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene is " a high-performance full-featured text search engine library [...]" by definition.
Analyzing the number of documents in which each term appears is easy to decide the order in which to perform the AND operations and Lucene and certainly does.

If you are interested in the algorithm, the best performance can be obtained executing the AND between the term with the lowest cardinalities, and goes on till the one with the highest.

In this way, thanks to the merge algorithm on the sorted posting lists [O(n+m) with n and m lengths of the two posting lists] and to the skip pointers, you can iterate over a of smaller number of docIDs.